# With MySQL, in a complex system, is it better to have a database with 1000 tables or multiple databases to split up the tables?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

My complex system has to do with collectables. I've got all kinds... movies, books, music, action figures, hot wheels, legos, video games, etc etc. Each collectable type has multiple tables associated with it with many difference references between each other. This leads to 100's, possible 1000's of tables, if this database continues to grow with new collectable types.

There are few tables they share in common. One is the barcode table, which has a key barcode that they all use. Another is a user_collection table, which stores all of a users collection, which has a collectable_id as a key. But that's about it (I might be missing a few but you get the point).

My question is, from a performance perspective, is it better to split these up into multiple databases (movies, books, comics, etc) or keep them in one database with all of the tables in it? Or does it even matter?

And if I do the split, how would I enforce the relationships I listed above?

Comment: asked previously. same answer: unless multi-tenenting, use many, related tables in a single DB

Comment: Still doesn't sound like 'thousands' though, does it? Maybe 'dozens'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to have a single database. Modern database systems are designed to handle large numbers of tables. It is more difficult to query across multiple databases.

Also, you need to think about recovery. If you have tables split across multiple databases, what happens when one of the databases gets destroyed? Will you have a synchronised set of database backups - because when you restore one database you will have to restore the other database(s) to the same point.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest using a single database, however, I cannot really see why you would need 1000s of tables.
For instance you could have a table for movies, books, but depending on the design, you probably won't need to have a separate table for each categories.
It is more likely to put all the item in one or two tables, and then have categories tables, linking them with a foreign key.
Even if it does grow to 100's of tables with 1000's of items, it shouldn't be a problem with a well designed database.

Comment: The are multiple many-to-many relationships, like Actors, Directors, Composer, etc. etc. that can add up quickly. And that's just for movies.

Comment: Ah, ok. Anyway, one database would definitely handle it. Are you planning on fully designing it to begin with or is it going to evolve over time?